# Solve an implicit function, power function with decimals

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, solver

I want to sove a implicit function, it's include power function and the index exists decimals.

I try to solve this by scipy, but it told me invalid value encountered in power, and I try to solve it by sympy, but no matter how long I wait, it can not output the answer.

Here is the implicit function
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW6y4.jpg

```
#####using scipy
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

global Ccu, Czn, EC50Cu, EC50Zn, bCu, bZn

Ccu = 1
Czn = 1

EC50Cu = 0.000419
bCu = 0.2388
EC50Zn = 0.9319
bZn = 0.50946

def fomula(a):
    # return Ccu/(EC50Cu * (((100-RRE)/RRE)**(1/bCu))) - 1
    return Ccu/EC50Cu + Czn/EC50Zn * a ** (1/bCu-1/bZn) - a ** (1/bCu)

a = fsolve(fomula, 0)

print(a)


#####using sympy
from sympy import *
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

EC50Cu = 0.000419
bCu = 0.2388
EC50Zn = 0.9319
bZn = 0.50946

Ccu = 1
Czn = 1

x = Symbol('x')

s = solve(Ccu/EC50Cu + Czn/EC50Zn * x ** (1/bCu-1/bZn) - x ** (1/bCu),x)
print(N(s[0],10))
```

Comment: The imgur link you posted shows the equation that you commented out

Comment: Also, the variable you are solving for is in the denominator, so it may be a problem with dividing by zero. When I choose other starting values the scipy function works, although I get different answers depending on whether I start with 1 or a higher number

Comment: In the image of the formula, the terms in parentheses are (100 - RRE)/RRR and (100 - RRE)/RRE.  Your code treats these as the same value.  Is RRR a mistake in the formula shown in the image?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

# input
Ccu,Czn = 1,1

EC50Cu = 0.000419
bCu = 0.2388
EC50Zn = 0.9319
bZn = 0.50946

# accuracy
acc = 0.001

for i in np.arange(1,99,acc):
    RRE = i
    a=Ccu/(EC50Cu * (((100-RRE)/RRE)**(1/bCu))) + Czn/(EC50Zn * (((100-RRE)/RRE)**(1/bZn)))
    if (a-1)>-acc and (a-1)<acc:
        print(i,a)
```

I have known the range of RRE, so I just to traverse the range, and to filter the answer what I want.

Answer (score 0):

When you want a numerical answer, consider using `nsolve` but you will need an initial guess...and some functions are more sensitive to this than others. But you can use SymPy to explore the function:

```
>>> eq = Ccu/EC50Cu + Czn/EC50Zn * x ** (1/bCu-1/bZn) - x ** (1/bCu)
>>> [(i, eq.subs(x,i).n(2)) for i in range(0,10,2)]
[(0, 2.4e+3), (2, 2.4e+3), (4, 2.1e+3), (6, 6.3e+2), (8, -3.6e+3)]
```

So it looks like there is a root between 6 and 8:

```
>>> nsolve(eq, 6)
6.44945374616155
```